# В библиотеке tkinter не производиться подщëт функции entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Вод код

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Hello wold")
window.geometry("300x300")       

def show_message():
    la = tk.Label(text=result)
    la.grid(column=1,row=3)
e = tk.Entry(window,width=10)
e.grid(column=1,row=1)
e=int(e)
d=70
result = e*70
b = tk.Button(window,text="если готово нажми",command=show_message)
b.grid(column=1,row=2)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Отстаньте со своим подщётом пожалуйста, вам всё ясно разъяснили.

Comment: @DaYa ну на самом деле никто до сих пор не разъяснил конкретно как правильно взаимодействовать с этим tk.Entry

Comment: @andreymal на самом деле, я человеку ясно дал понять что не нужно превращать `е` в `int()`

Comment: @DaYa вы конечно молодец, но так и не рассказали как правильно взаимодействовать с tk.Entry

Comment: @andreymal дал чёткий и простой в понимании для новичков ответ.

Comment: @DaYa стоило его в первом вопросе дать

Comment: @DaYa спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кушайте мой дорогой.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('Entry')
root.geometry('420x240')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False) #так можно зафиксировать размер окна

def on_click():
    number = int(val.get()) #для удобства понимания сделаем такую конструкцию
    lbl['text'] = number*70 #теперь буим умножать наше число на 70. Если пользователь введёт не число, будет ошибка

val = Entry(root) #условимся, здесь мы просто записываем ввод с текстового поля
val.pack()

btn = Button( #теперь давайте создадим кнопку чтоб получать наше значение
    root,
    text='Получить',
    font='Arial 10',
    bg='gray',
    command=on_click, #это функция для обработки нашего текстового поля
)
btn.pack()

lbl = Label(root, fg='blue')
lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```